# How to debug Ruby 2.1.1p76 with Intellij 12.1.7

Tags: ruby, debugging, intellij-idea, rubymine

How can I debug Ruby 2.1.1p76 with Intellij 12.1.7?  I can run my script just fine, but when I click the debug button, I get a dialog:

```
The gem ruby-debug-base required by the debugger is not currently installed. Would you like to install it?
```

When I click yes I get this:

```
10:36:21 AM Error running e2e
            Failed to Install Gems. Following gems were not installed:
            linecache (0.46):  Error installing linecache:
            ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.      /home/jared/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby extconf.rb Can't handle 1.9.x yet *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.  Provided configuration options:   --with-opt-dir  --without-opt-dir   --with-opt-include  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include    --with-opt-lib  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib    --with-make-prog    --without-make-prog     --srcdir=.  --curdir    --ruby=/home/jared/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby  extconf failed, exit code 1  Gem files will remain installed in /home/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/linecache-0.46 for inspection. Results logged to /home/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/linecache-0.46/gem_make.out
            /home/jared/.IntelliJIdea12/config/plugins/ruby/rb/gems/ruby-debug-base-0.10.5.rc1.gem:  Error installing ruby-debug-base-0.10.5.rc1.gem:
            ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.      /home/jared/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby extconf.rb Can't handle 1.9.x yet *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.  Provided configuration options:   --with-opt-dir  --without-opt-dir   --with-opt-include  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include    --with-opt-lib  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib    --with-make-prog    --without-make-prog     --srcdir=.  --curdir    --ruby=/home/jared/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby  extconf failed, exit code 1  Gem files will remain installed in /home/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/linecache-0.46 for inspection. Results logged to /home/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/linecache-0.46/gem_make.out
```

I realize that I could upgrade to Intellij 13 to fix this problem, but I don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ruby Remote Debug.

1. Install rdebug-ide:

   ```
   gem install ruby-debug-ide --pre
   ```
2. Create "Ruby remote debug" configuration in IDEA
3. Run your script from the terminal:

   ```
   rdebug-ide --port 1234 --dispatcher-port 26162 -- yourscript.rb
   ```
4. Press "Debug" in IDEA